# How using SET command with a call to CMD.EXE?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, environment-variables, console

I have to create system variable in Windows through calling CMD.Exe.
I try :

```
cmd.exe /C maVar=maVal
```

Saddly, no maVar is created.

If i open CMD.Exe and type :

```
maVar=maVal
```

-> maVar is created.

Saddly, i have to do it through calling cmd.exe, not launching cmd.exe.
Anyone know what is ly mistake ?

Thanks

Comment: So it appears by your comment in the answer below that you did not read the post @Ramhound pointed you at.  The answer below is not only a duplicate, it is of lower quality than the reference Ramhound provided.  Yes, setting *permanent* variables from the windows command prompt is kinda wonkie.. but that is true in all operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setx` command to create system variable, `set` command define variables only inside of current cmd session.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it, but when i type "set" in order to see all my variables, my variables is not in the list.

Comment: @WalterFabioSimoni - Depending on if you are setting the system or user variable you might have to close the command prompt session.

Comment: you have to reopen new cmd windows to see created system variable, cmd.exe read system variables only once when it starting